# How to filter nested list based on prefix of string in columns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, filter, nested, prefix

**My problem:**

I would like to get the names which miss ages. For next sample data:

```
t = ([Mike, 12], [Alice, 20], [Bob, Missing_1], [Jack, Missing_2])
```

The output should be:

```
Bob
Jack
```

**What I tried?**

```
r=([l for l in t[1] if l='Missing*'])
```

It didn't work out. Does wildcard work in Python?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
print([e for e, age in t if isinstance(age, str) and 'missing' in age.lower()])
```

**Output**

```
['Bob', 'Jack']
```

If the output must be a string you can change it to:

```
print(' '.join([e for e, age in t if isinstance(age, str) and 'missing' in age.lower()]))
```

**Output**

```
Bob Jack
```

The `'missing' in age.lower()` checks that `'missing'` is part of the string `age`, before that we check that `age` is indeed a string with `isinstance(age, str)`.  If the missing values are always string you can use only the `isinstance(age, str)`. Note that this solution assumes the missing values are strings that contain the word missing.

An alternative, more in line with your attempted solution, is the [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) function, from the documentation:

> Return True if string starts with the prefix, otherwise return False

```
print(' '.join([e for e, age in t if isinstance(age, str) and age.startswith('Missing')])
```

**Output**

```
Bob Jack
```